# .htaccess Variable Redirection Issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am having trouble redirecting my variables.
How do I redirect everything so when user goes to `http://domain.com/v1/v2/`, it actually does the `http://domain.com/index.php?a1=v1&a2=v2`?

Sorry for my bad English. I have tried many things and failed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?a1=$1&a2=$2
```

Comment: Awesome this one does exactly what I need. https://v1k.org/personal/redirect/test/test/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the following one, but try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) ./index.php?a1=$1&a2=$2
```

Let me know if you have any suggestion or problems, you are facing

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php          [NC]
RewriteRule .*    index.php?a1=%1&a2=%2         [L]
```

Internally maps:

`http://domain.com/v1/v2/` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://domain.com/index.php?a1=v1&a2=v2`

Strings `v1` and `v2` are assumed to be dynamic while `index.php` is assumed to be fixed.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`.

Comment: Whenever I tried this it would actually redirect me to index.php, and the only thing I wanted was pretty URLs. Thanks anyways, it will be useful one day; I up voted! ;)